# "Output only" - IO Expander Question

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, gpio, io

I see on the datasheet for the [MCP23017](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP23017-Data-Sheet-DS20001952.pdf) that the GPA7 and GPB7 pins can only be outputs per the latest revision.

Can anyone explain why this is? Is it okay to still use it as input, but just decreased reliability?

Comment: Please [Edit] to give a page reference. The datasheet is 46 pages long. Thanks.

Comment: @Transistor page 1 and page 18, but [of a different PDF](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP23017-Data-Sheet-DS20001952.pdf).

Comment: @Transistor - Please check the link in the edited question.

Comment: If you want to experiment with something that the datasheet warns you against, your best option is to get your hands on a physical IC and try it yourself. According to Digikey, you can buy one for $2. It's anyone's guess whether the device will still work, break the I2C routine, let the smoke out, or induce the nasal demons.

Comment: @MattS , just to be safe, I am asking here as many might have had some experiences on a similar scenario

Comment: Is this the same (?) ... https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf

Comment: If the manufacturer tells you that something got broken in a new revision (see Appendix A, revision history, mention of revision D from June 2022), chances are high that they're right.

Answer (score 4):

It's explained in [GPA7 & GPB7 Cannot Be Used as Inputs In MCP23017](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/GPA7---GPB7-Cannot-Be-Used-as-Inputs-In-MCP23017):

> In the datasheet Revision D (June 2022), GPA7 & GPB7 are mentioned as outputs only for MCP23017. But, the register bits do allow for the direction of these I/O pins to be changed to inputs. However, the SDA signal can be corrupted during a reading of these bits if the pin voltage changes during the transmission of the bit. It has also been reported that this SDA corruption can cause some bus hosts to malfunction. In conclusion, GPA7 & GPB7 should only be used as outputs to avoid future issues.

To answer your question: it might work, it's up to you to take that risk. Personally, I prefer to stick with the vendor recommendations and avoid wasting time troubleshooting weird i2c issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are six references to GPA7 in the [datasheet linked in your original question](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf). Four are on the pinout diagrams, one on the Functional Block Diagram and the sixth in Table 2-1 which states:

> GPA7: I/O **Bidirectional I/O pin**. Can be enabled for interrupt-on-change and/or internal weak pull-up resistor.

This is exactly the same as all the other pins on GPA and GPB.

---

For the [second datasheet], section 3.5.1 states:

> Note: **For MCP23017, IO7 must be set via I2C interface to "0" (output)**.

It looks pretty definitive (and strange) to me.

Comment: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP23017-Data-Sheet-DS20001952.pdf - Can you check this in the datasheet.

Comment: Page 11 of the datasheet and other references of GPA7.

Comment: Can the pin by used as an Input ? Or only output? Why do you think its strange?

Comment: According to the datasheet it can only be used as an output. It's strange because it reduces the number of inputs from 16 to 14 and usually all port pins are identical.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What do you think / suggest on my original question? Whether it can be used an input with reduced reliability?

Comment: There is no information there for me to form an opinion to answer that question. There may not even be an input circuit on the chip.

Comment: It looks like somebody f'd up a die shrink or something, and they decided to document it as a "feature" rather than listing it as a bug/erratum. Remember, the only difference between a bug and a feature is documentation!

Answer (score 0):

I heard (can't remember exactly where, unfortunately) that a bug was recently identified in the I2C logic that was enabled when either port's pin 7 was configured as an output, but was in some way intermittent. The strong implication is this is not a new bug, but one that has existed for some time.

I am unconvinced that there is a distinct 'rev D', more that the docs now refer to current devices that way. On Microchip's site there is no mention of an additional die respin.

As of 2024 the errata document only mentions rev A1 as being current: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/80252A.pdf